# Python parse embedding in c

Tags: python, c, parsing, embedding

I'm trying to embedding two python functions in C code. My problem is that I can't parse None py object to NULL in C.

I created a "check.py" file within it:

```
def integer(s):
    a = input(s)
    try:
        a = int(a)
        return a
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input\n")
        return #NULL

def floating(s):
    a = input(s)
    try:
        a = float(a)
        return a
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input\n")
        return #NULL
```

Here is the C code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int inputInt() {
    PyObject *strret, *mymod, *strfunc, *strargs;
    int result;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.')");
    mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("prova");
    strfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymod, "integer");
    strargs = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "Insert an integer value: ");
    strret = PyEval_CallObject(strfunc, strargs);
    //next line is the problem (can't parse None py object to NULL)
    PyArg_Parse(strret, "l", &result);
    return result;
}

double inputDouble() {
    PyObject *strret, *mymod, *strfunc, *strargs;
    double result;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.')");
    mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("prova");
    strfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymod, "floating");
    strargs = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "Insert a floating point value: ");
    strret = PyEval_CallObject(strfunc, strargs);
    //next line is the problem (can't parse None py object to NULL)
    PyArg_Parse(strret, "d", &result);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long a = inputInt();
    printf("%ld\n", a);
    double b = inputDouble();
    printf("%.3f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

The program compile correctly but how can I implement None object to NULL in C?

Comment: Have you checked that `strret` is not [`Py_None`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html)?